# Using testcafe with random page paths

Tags: reactjs, random, automated-tests, integration-testing, testcafe

My react app uses a UUID to identify a certain type of object. This is also used in the page path.
`mysite.com/thing/uuid-for-one-of-the-things`

This type of object changes constantly, so a UUID that exists one day, may not exist another.

I use testcafe for my other pages. I load a page with

```
fixture('Cool Page')
  .page('mysite.com/coolPage/a-cool-thing-that-is-not-random')
```

How would I load and test a page that has a random path?

I'm open to suggestions about modifying my design to not use UUIDs, or perhaps using a different testing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test a page, you need to know to navigate to it. 
So, you should have a way to get the URL of the page (links on the another web page, generated file with links, etc.).
It doesn't depend on the testing framework, programming language and so on.

Comment: I will start testing on the previous page to get the link to the page I want to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a test page for a particular test usign the [test.page()](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#specifying-the-start-webpage) function or the t.navigateTo() action. Also, take a look at the [Data-Driven Tests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/create-data-driven-tests.html) approach, it seems to be suitable for your case.